# Powershell While loop at a specific time

Tags: powershell

I would like to stop and start a process at a specific time using `powershell` , i dont want to use `Task Scheduler`, i have written something like below

```
while($true){
    Start-Process "abc"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 
    get-process abc|Stop-Process 
    }
```

The above script start the process every 1hr, but i want the same thing to be done at a specific time say `5PM` everyday rather than every 1hr. I am not sure how do i approach this, any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Why not use the task scheduler? It is designed to do exactly this.

Comment: Using a Scheduled Task is really the best approach here. Otherwise, the script needs to be running all day, checking every x minutes if the current computer time is at 5PM (or part of a minute later)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that process dint have proper access if it is run through task scheduler, different issue altogether.

Comment: If you can run the script yourself, then you can run it using the scheduler. (The scheduler supports running a program using the current credentials.) Other than that I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would eschew Task Scheduler. This is, as it sounds, Windows' way of scheduling tasks to run. Most tools I know of which enable this functionality still use Task Scheduler to schedule the executions. Even the super-easy-to-use-but-now-defunct `at` command scheduled things to run via Task Scheduler.

That said you could just have your script run for a long time, checking the time constantly, this would work but if you script exits you will need to restart it. You effectively need to write a "service", with a loop that won't terminate under most circumstances (`while($true)` will suffice here).

```
Start-Transcript C:\path\to\transcript.log -Append

# Use 24 hour time
$runAt = Get-Date -Hour 17 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$now = Get-Date

$timeFormat = 'HH:mm'

# If we're after the time for today, add a day
if ( $runAt -lt $now ) {

  $runAt.AddDays(1)
}

while ( $true ) {

  $now = Get-Date
  if ( $runAt.ToString($timeFormat) -eq $now.ToString($timeFormat) ) {

    try {
      # Your code here
      # Don't forget to clean up your variables so GC frees up memory
      # e.g. Remove-Variable, $var = $null, etc.

    }
    catch {
      # Write the error but don't blow up
      $_
    }
    finally {

      # We need to add a day to the next run, and let's schedule the GC
      # to run while we sleep
      $runAt.AddDays(1)
      [System.GC]::Collect(
        0,
        [System.GCCollectionMode]::Optimized,
        $false
      )
    }
  }
  else {
    if ( $runAt -lt $now ) {
      $runAt.AddDays(1)
    }
  }
  
  # Check every minute since you aren't using a scheduler
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Note that as written, the script will not terminate unless you stop the process.

Comment: oops..lot of syntax errors. correcting them now

Comment: I accidentally removed the `try` keyword and missed a comma. This should work now.